# Is this a memory leak? Winforms hiding and showing forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, memory-leaks

I am using the following code to hide a form and show a new one (basically, I want to switch between two forms). But each time I press button2 or button1 memory usage of my application in task manager increases. This memory usage grows each time I click my buttons and it is never released until Application.Exit(). Is this some sort of memory leak? Am I managing my forms wrongly?

Thank you very much.

FORM 1:

```
Form2 pform2;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (form2 != null)
    {
        pform2.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        pform2 = new Form2();
        pform2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    this.Hide();
```

FORM 2

```
Form1 pform1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (form1 != null)
    {
        pform1.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        pform1 = new Form1();
        pform1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    this.Hide();
```

Comment: People, who looking up for memory leaks using task manager must not use computers any more.

Comment: @Dennis For a simple look on memory consumption it is more then sufficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the debugger you would clearly see what is going on.
The issue is that everytime you click the button a new instance of either `Form1` or `Form2` is created. The field `pform1` eg. `pform2` is then null every time, so a new instance is created when clicking the button.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public class Main
{
  public Main()
  {
    var form = new Form1();
    form.ShowDialog();
  }
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
  private readonly Form2 _form2;

  public Form1()
    : this(null)
  {
    _form2 = new Form2(this);
  }

  public Form1(Form2 form2)
  {
    _form2 = form2;
    var button = new Button();
    button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
    Controls.Add(button);
  }

  private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    this.Hide();
    _form2.Show();
  }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
  private readonly Form1 _form1;

  public Form2(Form1 form2)
  {
    _form1 = form2;
    var button = new Button();
    button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
    Controls.Add(button);
  }

  private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    this.Hide();
    _form1.Show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure if my program was memory leaking or not and your answer proved useful :)

Comment: mind if I ask something? Visual studio is telling me that the form2 and form1 inside the IFs conditions do not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Aturo I've udpated my example to a complete one which you can run just like it is

Comment: With your code it sill adds more and more RAM usage whenever you click on the button... but I guess that I shouldn't trust task manager, then. :)

Comment: I ran the code and hit the buttons for 1 minute with my memory profiler attached and I did not see any memory increase

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't know how to track memory usage properly. I've recorded a video of this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEty7hitjhM) If that is completely normal behaviour then ignore me. And sorry to bother you again! :)

Comment: I can't really see any significant increase of memory, some fluctuation in kB range is quite normal

Answer (score 1):

Based on code you've provided: you are not "switching" between forms, **you're creating new forms each time**.

Suppose you are in `Form1` and pressing your button. Then `pform2` will be created and shown, but since you are not passing your `Form1` instance to `pform2` - it will have null in `pform1`, so when you will press button in that form, **new** instance of `Form1` will be created and shown and so on.....

Comment: Thank you very much! If I could mark two posts as answer I would mark yours too. Really useful :)

Comment: @Andy_Korneyev It seems I need 15 points of reputation (which I do not have yet) Sorry :(